# Does Sympy 0.7.1 work with Jython?

Tags: jython, sympy

Does anybody now whether sympy 0.7.1 will work with Jython?

Answer (score 3):

No, it doesn't work - I think it doesn't even import. There's [an open issue for this](http://code.google.com/p/sympy/issues/detail?id=1233) in sympy's bug tracker. The development version should import fine, but there are problems still.

Comment: Yeah, Ronan is right - it just doesn't work. If you are interesting in making it work, you could try commenting on the issue. (at the very least, star it: you'll be notified on any updates and the developers will note people are interested)

Answer (score 0):

It's late but for all future readers:

As of Jython-2.7.1, it can import SymPy and most of SymPy works on it.

However, it is very slow compared to CPython possibly due to this issue http://bugs.jython.org/issue2604. See #4332.

You can download the Jython-2.7.1 from [mvnrepository](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.python/jython-standalone/2.7.1). If it shows you 0 Bytes then you can use this [alternate link](http://central.maven.org/maven2/org/python/jython-standalone/2.7.1/)